# JSON Stringify not indenting properly in <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the JSON.stringify() function on a Javascript object but the indentation on the first curly brace doesn't look correct. The first line is indented, but everything else looks fine. I did some research, and another answer on StackOverflow suggested to use the `<pre>` tag. Ideas?

My javascript code:

```
var result = {
    name: "Jim Cowart",
    location: {
        city: {
            name: "Chattanooga",
            population: 167674
        },
        state: {
            name: "Tennessee",
            abbreviation: "TN",
            population: 6403000
        }
    },
    company: "appendTo",
};

$scope.data = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

My HTML code:

```
<pre content-load id="json-data">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <span>{{ data }}</span>
</pre>
```

What actually renders in the browser (took a snapshot):

[image: Snapshot of JSON Stringify]

Comment: `<pre>` tags will render ALL whitespace, including the newlines and tabs you added in your code. Try putting it all on one line instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have indentation before `<span>`, and `<pre>` means that this should be preserved in the rendering. Try:

```
<pre pams-content-load id="json-data">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <span>
{{ data }}</span>
</pre>
```

so that the data is at the beginning of the line. Or put `<pre>` only around the JSON span.

```
<div class="loader"></div>
    <pre pams-content-load id="json-data"><span>{{ data }}</span></pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Why does the indentation of the tags themselves influence how the text is rendered in the browser?

Comment: `<pre>`  means to keep all the whitespace in the block when you render it. That includes the spaces before the `<div>` and `<span>` tags.